# session(_:activationDidCompleteWith:error:) not called on Apple Watch (but is called in Simulator)

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchconnectivity

I've created a simple swift class:

```
import Foundation
import WatchConnectivity

class WatchCommunication : NSObject, WCSessionDelegate {

    var session: WCSession!

    override init() {
        super.init()

        if WCSession.isSupported() {
            print("WCSession is supported")
            self.session = WCSession.default
            self.session.delegate = self
            if session.activationState == WCSessionActivationState.activated {
                print("activationState is activated")
            } else {
                print("activationState is not activated")
                self.session.activate()
            }
        } else {
            print("WCSession is not supported")
        }
    }

    func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
        print("activationState", activationState.rawValue)
        print(error)
    }
}
```

In my Watch App Extension I load create an instance of this class

```
class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate {

    let watchCommunication: WatchCommunication = WatchCommunication() 

    // ...
```

When I test this code in the simulator, I see the following logged

```
 WCSession is supported
 activationState is not activated
 activationState 2
 nil
```

All working fine.
When I run the same application on my testing iPhone X and paired Apple Watch 3, the logs show

```
 WCSession is supported
 activationState is not activated
```

So it seems that the method

```
 func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
```

is never called on my Apple Watch.

Methods like

```
 func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : Any]) {
```

are also not called on device (but are working on the simulator).

On the iPhone X side of things, the `actionDidCompleteWith` method is called, with `activationState` 2 (`activated`) and `updateApplicationContext` does not throw an error.

There is however communication between the iPhone and Apple Watch, because the method https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkhealthstore/1648358-startwatchapp does indeed start a workout on the watch (and all Apple and third party watch apps work normally).

Answer (score 1):

For further reference:

Restarting my Apple Watch (what I **never** do otherwise) did solve the issue...